# Working live at Server / SSH

Tags: apache, ssh, hosting

I've inherited a website to build. I've just come to realization that the website's server is not typical to what I've always worked with; EG - I usually create an FTP with the hosting account and work live at **http://www.mycoolclients.com/dev/index.html**

I've found that I must connect using; SSH. I have little direct server experience. I'm told I need to work with linux or download something like 'putty'. How do I connect to work live at this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `sftp` instead of `ftp`.**

Learning how to use ssh would definitely be valuable as it's widely used and extremely useful, but in the immediate you can just use sftp for anything that you previously used ftp for.  sftp will give you the same interface as ftp, but connects via ssh.

You didn't mention what ftp software you use, but many also support connecting via sftp.

Comment: I use both Dreamweaver CS4 + FileZilla.

Comment: I've connected via sftp; but am now having trouble determining where I am at. The website has a default wordpress install at the root but I cannot find 'index.php'; I believe I am in the root as well -- why would this be hidden. I've also gotten a 'permission denied' error while trying to create a file?!

Comment: @cam77 I can't help with the vagaries of that server's layout, but in general `sftp` will start you in the home directory of the user used to connect, e.g., connecting as user bob will start you in `/home/bob`.